# StatusCode: 409 cuando se envían cifras decimales en un StringContent C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código de prueba:

```cs
protected async void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //var jsonSerializerOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };
    Models.Clientes1 objCliente = new Models.Clientes1();
    objCliente.Nombre = "Cliente Nuevo";
    objCliente.Telefono = "1234567";
    objCliente.Credito = 1000;
    objCliente.Moroso = 1;
    //string data = "{\"nombre\":\"Para Borrar\",\"telefono\":\"414\",\"credito\":777,\"moroso\":1}";
    HttpClient objHttpClient = new HttpClient();
    var data1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objCliente);
    var content = new StringContent(data1,System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");
    var respuesta=await objHttpClient.PostAsync("http://localhost:17793/api/Clientes2/", content);
    Label1.Text = respuesta.ToString();
}
```

Cuando envío *data1* en *content* de `objHttpClient.PostAsync`, se agrega una cifra decimal en crédito (1000.0) que genera un `StatusCode: 409`.
Sin embargo cuando envío *data* (el json manual) o cuando al depurar quito la cifra decimal, el `StatusCode` en `201`.

Les agradezo si me pueden indicar a qué se debe y cómo se soluciona sin hacer conversiones a `String`.

La cadena completa de la respuesta en cada caso es:

> StatusCode: 201, ReasonPhrase: 'Created', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcY2FybG9cc291cmNlXHJlcG9zXHByb3llY3RvQVBJVmFyaWFzQkRccHJveWVjdG9BUElWYXJpYXNCRFxhcGlcQ2xpZW50ZXMyXA==?= Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 11 May 2021 17:25:42 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 22 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 }

> StatusCode: 409, ReasonPhrase: 'Conflict', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers: { Pragma: no-cache X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcY2FybG9cc291cmNlXHJlcG9zXHByb3llY3RvQVBJVmFyaWFzQkRccHJveWVjdG9BUElWYXJpYXNCRFxhcGlcQ2xpZW50ZXMyXA==?= Cache-Control: no-cache Date: Tue, 11 May 2021 17:26:45 GMT Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319 X-Powered-By: ASP.NET Content-Length: 32 Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8 Expires: -1 }

Comment: Probaste usando Double en vez de decimal? segun lei es un problema del NewtonsoftJson al serializar el objeto

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Carlos Marcelo. Si. En modelo de la aplicación cliente cambié el tipo decimal por double y luego por Double y nada. Tambien deberia hacerlo en el modelo de la API?